# Programmatically Upload larger Files in Flex

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, file-upload

I created an application as part of an ASP.NET site. I would like to receive error notifications in my inbox whenever something goes wrong with that flash application.

As I do not have control over our mail server (which has a different domain name), I cannot establish a cross domain policy allowing me to send error emails to my inbox.

Instead, thought I'd send a request to an ASP.NET handler that sends an email on behalf of the flash app.

Now the problem: the error report should include a screenshot of the flash application at the time the error occurred. The FileReference class however only allows file uploads with user interaction (browse dialog) and cannot be used programmatically to send the screenshot to my ASP.NET handler. The plain old POST back only allows files up to ~200K.

Am I missing something or is there no alternative to :

- using POST w/ a compressed or resized screenshot
- or forcing the user to first save a screenshot and then select it for upload?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Is the 200K limit something you're seeing in Flex or on your ASP server?  We've had to up some PHP limits on our backend to support similar workarounds to the file upload restriction.

Comment: Thanks. It was a problem in the web service and not in Flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lay in the receiving web service, not in Flex.